# how can uploaded multi images in this class

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

i want to upload multi images in my database just url images the code is work fine but i can upload just one image i need to upload 3 images i have in database table e_img - e_img2 - e_img3 how can upload images url in 3 columns

this my class upload :

```
        <?php
       class Upload {

       private $allowedExts = array('doc','docx','pdf','txt','jpg','png');
       private $maxSize;
       private $file;
       private $uploadsDirecotry;
       private $fileUrl;
       private $filenames = array();

       function __construct($file,$allowedExts,$uploadsDirecotry,$maxSize){
           if(is_array($allowedExts) AND is_int($maxSize)){
             $this->file  = $file;
             $this->allowedExts = $allowedExts;
             $this->maxSize = $maxSize;
             $this->uploadsDirecotry = $uploadsDirecotry;

           }else{
             throw new Exception("File extension must be in an array and max size value must be intger value.");
           }

           }
       function uploadFiles(){

            $file = $this->file;
            $allowedExts = $this->allowedExts;
            $maxsize = $this->maxSize;
            $uploadsDir = $this->uploadsDirecotry;

        for($i = 0; $i < count($file['name']); $i++){

          $errors = array();

          // print_r($_FILES);
          $filename    = $file['name'][$i];
          $fileext    = strtolower(end(explode('.',$filename)));
          $filesize    = $file['size'][$i];
          $filetmpname = $file['tmp_name'][$i];

        if(in_array($fileext, $allowedExts) === FALSE){
           $errors[] = "Extension in sot allowed";
        }

         if($filesize > $maxsize){
            $errors[] = "File size must be less than {$maxsize} KB !";
         }

         if(empty($errors)){

            $random = rand(0,199);
            $this->fileUrl = $random . "_" . date("d-m-Y") . "_" . $filename;
            $destination = $uploadsDir. $random."_".date("d-m-Y") . "_" . $filename;
            move_uploaded_file($filetmpname, $destination);
            $this->filenames[] = $this->fileUrl;

         }else{

           foreach($errors as $error){
            throw new Exception($error);
           }
         }
              } // end for

              return TRUE;
       }

       function getFileUrl()
       {
             return $this->fileUrl;
           }

       function getFilesNames()
       {
             return $this->filenames;
           }

       }


    ?>
```

and this html php file

```
        <?php include 'header.php';

                if(isset($_POST['add']))
                {
                    $e_title    = $_POST['e_title'];
                    $e_user     = $userRow['user_name'];    

                 try{
                    include 'models/Upload.php';
                    $file = $_FILES['e_img'];
                    $allowedExts = array('jpg','png','gif','jpeg');
                    $uploadsDirectory = "imgupload/";
                    $maxSize = 4000000;
                    $upload = new Upload($file, $allowedExts, $uploadsDirectory, $maxSize);
                    $upload->uploadFiles();
                    $e_img = $uploadsDirectory.$upload->getFileUrl();

                  }catch(Exception $exc){
                    echo'<div class="alert alert-block alert-danger">fail image uploaded</div>';
                    exit;}


                        $insert = $user->insert($e_title,$e_img,$e_user);

                        echo"<div class='alert alert-block alert-success'>Save success</div>";
                        exit;
            }

            ?>
                <form action='newads.php' method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                   <p>إضافة صور </p>
                    <input type="file" name='e_img[]' id="exampleInputFile">
                    <input  type="submit" name='add' class='btn btn-primary' value='add' />
              </form>


    <?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

i try this but But it did not succeed

```
    <form action='newads.php' method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>إضافة صور </p>
    <input type="file" name='e_img[]' id="exampleInputFile">
    <input type="file" name='e_img2[]' id="exampleInputFile">
    <input type="file" name='e_img3[]' id="exampleInputFile">
    <input  type="submit" name='add' class='btn btn-primary' value='add' />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to increment the field names in your file fields.   That will break the array when PHP receives it.  Change to this:  (they should all be `e_img[]`

```
<input type="file" name='e_img[]' id="exampleInputFile">
<input type="file" name='e_img[]' id="exampleInputFile">
<input type="file" name='e_img[]' id="exampleInputFile">
```

Comment: but e_img is name for 1 columns in table i have 3 columns e_img / e_img2 / e_img3 and i want to uploaded url image in 3 columns

Comment: The upload class you are using loops through the array of file objects.  Adding `[]` to the end of a field name indicates to PHP that those matching objects should be in an array for further processing.  Incrementing the field name before the array brackets means you will only get the first one to upload, as the upload class only sees one object in that array.  You also have the same ID attached to each, which shouldn't affect the upload but would affect any JS/CSS applied as HTML ID tags are supposed to be unique.

Comment: i have this problem now i want tgo get fullname image http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33318470/get-image-name-after-uploaded

help me please

Comment: @HassanIbra if it fixed it as you said in [this comment...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33318470/get-upload-directory#comment54434901_33318470) left in your other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/33318470/, then mark this answer as correct.